# How to fetch YOAST SEO plugin data using WP REST API plugin ? Specially the wpseo_head hook content

Tags: wordpress, api, seo

I'm using WP REST API to fetch all the post data. Well, it works perfectly, but the major concern for any website is the SEO part. I'm using YOAST SEO plugin. I want to fetch all the Meta tags it creates in the Head section of HTML.

FYI im using Wordpress as Backend and Nodejs in frontend.

---

The solution is simple. I have added custom endpoints in the function.php file. You can see this [Adding Custom Endpoints](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding)

Comment: Solution is simple.

Comment: What was the custom endpoint that you wrote?