# How to include Yoast SEO data in Wordpress Custom Endpoint

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I have a custom endpoint created following the official [guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) 
and in it, I'm simply fetching the post by slug (name) as follows:

```
if ( $posts = get_posts( array(
    'name' => $slug,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
) ) ) $post = $posts[0];

if ( empty( $post ) ) {
    return null;
}
```

Preparing the response as adding more data about the author, preparing some custom fields etc.

The problem I'm facing is we have **Yoast SEO** plugin added and in the standard WP REST API *yoast_head* is included but in the custom endpoint, it's not.

I found this [article](https://developer.yoast.com/blog/yoast-seo-rest-api-endpoint/) where it lists that the SEO data is included in the standard REST API and that there is a custom endpoint for fetching the SEO data

Example:
`https://example/wp-json/yoast/v1/get_head?url=https://example.com/hello-world/`

That would mean I would be required to make an additional request just to fetch the SEO data.

I also tried activating ***WP REST Yoast Meta*** plugin without success as it throws an error while fetching the regular WP REST and it had no effect on the custom one

Is there a way to get **yoast_head** in the custom endpoint?

Comment: You can try with custom end points Have look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290983/how-to-fetch-yoast-seo-plugin-data-using-wp-rest-api-plugin-specially-the-wpse and here https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: The source code for generating this is very complex and nested, your best bet would be to just use the get_head endpoint within your function and use a php get request to append the data

Comment: I don't have time to write up a full testable answer, but you can just use Yoast's API's natively in your own code. Unfortunately Yoast is going/went through a rewrite so their code might not be obvious if you don't know how they did DI, however they still have a [legacy version in their deprecated section](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/trunk/deprecated/frontend/frontend.php) that should get you the code that you need to use. Obviously, all warnings about using code explicitly marked as deprecated apply.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and this worked for me, i hope it helps you. The Meta_Surface class provides a helper for access the head of any post or page.

```
  if (function_exists('YoastSEO')) {
        $meta_helper = YoastSEO()->classes->get(Yoast\WP\SEO\Surfaces\Meta_Surface::class);
        $meta = $meta_helper->for_post($pid);
        $query->post->yoast_head = $meta->get_head();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Just exactly what I was searching.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need, I faced the same issue and someone coded this for this exact purpose:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-yoast-meta/

Keep me posted!

Answer (score 0):

To everyone struggling with the same issue: Do as Francisco's answer, but add this at the top: `WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance();`
Reference: https://yoast.com/developer-blog/yoast-seo-14-0-using-yoast-seo-surfaces/